# Mongoose push id from films to users table and js syntax problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have a problem with the payment API function with #node js #express js which will be consumed by the mobile part, I would like that after the payment made the film.free attribute will have the value true and put the id of movie in users_payement table in users model and then video streaming will take place.
my problem is that film.free get true value before payment made and I failed to save the movie id as shown above.
i'm using mongoose node js and express js ans stripe for payment

film.controller.js

```
const Film = require("../models/film.model")
const fs = require("fs");
const User=require('../models/user.model')

module.exports={
pay:function(req,res) {
    
      Film.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function (err,film){
        if (err){
            res.status(500).json({ message:"Internal server error" }); 
        }else{
            if(film.free==false){
            
                fs.readFile(publicPath + '/try.html',null,function(error,data){
                    if(error){
                        console.log('not ok')
                    }else{
                        res.end(data)
                    }  
                    })      
        }
        
        else{
            const range = req.headers.range;
            if (!range) {
                res.status(400).send("Requires Range header");
            }
            const videoPath = film.file.path;
            const videoSize = fs.statSync(videoPath).size;
            const CHUNK_SIZE = 10 ** 6; // 1MB
            const start = Number(range.replace(/\D/g, ""));
            const end = Math.min(start + CHUNK_SIZE, videoSize - 1);
            const contentLength = end - start + 1;
            const headers = {
                "Content-Range": `bytes ${start}-${end}/${videoSize}`,
                "Accept-Ranges": "bytes",
                "Content-Length": contentLength,
                "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
            };
            res.writeHead(206, headers);
            const videoStream = fs.createReadStream(videoPath, { start, end });
            videoStream.pipe(res);
        }
        }})},}
```

user.model.js

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let UserShema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  email: {type: String},
  age: {type: Number},
  mobile: {type: String},
  fidelity: {type: Number,default:0},
  password: {type: String},
  created_at : {type: Date,default:new Date()},
  disabled : {type: Boolean,default:false},
  deleted : {type: Boolean,default:false},
  films_payment:[
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "films"
    }
  ]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('users', UserShema);
```

film.model.js

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let FilmShema = new Schema({
  title: {type: String},
  category: {type: String},
  description: {type: String},
  publish_date: {type: String},
  cover: {type:Schema.Types.Mixed},
  file:{type:Schema.Types.Mixed},
  free:{type: Boolean,default:true},
  price: {type: Number,default:0},
  deleted : {type: Boolean,default:false},
  created_at : {type: Date,default:new Date()},
  users_payment:[
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "users"
    }
  ]
});

FilmShema.index({ title: 'text',category: 'text',  description: 'text' }, {name: 'relevance', weights: {title: 5,category:5, description: 1}});

module.exports = mongoose.model('films', FilmShema);
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var http = require('http');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index.route');
var app = express();
const server = http.Server(app);
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
publicPath=path.join(__dirname, './public');
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51IsQu0Lqx9gs2tzKV8wpSjQW4DYUTaZWnQRPC8HtVUI3m6KlZ55BusJqvUQfytan5PhRcpKLbW9s2aDRMQlvgP0L008yE9fMXC')
var db=require("./db/config")
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
  next()
}),
// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.json({limit: '2048mb', extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '2048mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 1000000 }));


app.post('/payment', function(req, res){ 
  // Moreover you can take more details from user 
  // like Address, Name, etc from form 
  stripe.customers.create({ 
      email: req.body.stripeEmail, 
      source: req.body.stripeToken, 
      name:req.body.name, 
      address: { 
          line1: 'Rue Mohamed chetoui', 
          postal_code: '5180', 
          city: 'kssour essef', 
          state: 'Mahdia', 
          country: 'Tunisia', 
      } 
  }) 
  .then((customer) => { 

      return stripe.charges.create({ 
          amount: 3000,    // Charing Rs 25 
          description: 'Web Development Product', 
          currency: 'USD', 
          customer: customer.id 
      }); 
  }) 
  .then((charge) => { 
    res.send('sucess') // If no error occurs 
  }) 
  .catch((err) => { 
      res.send(err)    // If some error occurs 
  }); 
}) 
app.listen(port, function(error){ 
  if(error) throw error 
  console.log("Server created Successfully") 
})

//make folder uploads/public => public

app.use('/uploads/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads/public')));
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')))
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use('/api', indexRouter);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("server is running " +port)
})
module.exports = app;
module.exports = {
payement:('/payement')
};
```

index.html under public folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
   <head>
       <meta-charest="UTF-8">
<title>Stripe Payment Demo</title> 

<body> 
   <h3>Welcome to Payment Gateway</h3> 
   <form action="http://localhost:3000/payment" method="POST"> 
   <script
       src="//checkout.stripe.com/v2/checkout.js"
       class="stripe-button"
       data-key="pk_test_51IsQu0Lqx9gs2tzKW9cJ0lStPNPyhf9OMFji0V4380XdNGpmTzLxnA1nlTs0QVQo0QYIZan5t8Ut4jR5Z4DjXioA00jIsI6KAW"
       data-currency="usd" 
       data-name="Gautam Sharma" 
       data-description="Buy React.js Complete Course" 
       data-locale="auto" > 
       </script> 
   </form> 
</body> 
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8015757/onur-%c3%96zk%c4%b1r can you help me please or if you know some one who can help i am really in need